# How to display Unicode in TChart labels

Tags: delphi, unicode, teechart

I have a TChart object where I want to be able to display Unicode characters for the axis labels.

Any help would be appreciated.

Addendum : Delphi 5.0

Comment: What version of Delphi? D2009 and later are Unicode aware; prior versions are not.

Comment: The solution is to upgrade to modern Delphi.

Comment: You might be interested to know that if you buy Delphi XE2, you gain access to prior versions, which would allow you to port up to Dephi 2007 first, which should be pretty trivial, and then port up to Delphi XE2.  There are lots of documents and tutorials on porting and updating your app for newer delphi versions.  no need to be afraid.

Comment: I have no idea why people upvoted those answers.  If I wanted to upgrade I would have done so.  If I asked 'how do I change a tyre' - would you suggest buying a new car?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to write a simple TChart yourself and use code from the [TMS Unicode](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsuni.asp) (formerly known ans TNT Unicode) component collection code. The TMS package supports Delphi 6 and higher, but the source code is included. Maybe the original TNT source code is still somewhere on the Internet, it was open source.

Comment: TNT controls with source are hosted here : [tntunicodecontrols](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/tntunicodecontrols/index)

Answer (score 2):

Unicode support wasn't introduced in Delphi until 2009 version so you should use TeeChart for Delphi 2009 or above to get native Unicode support.